# Products not available in each store

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of tables

**Product**

```
{  ProdID (INT),  Name(varchar),   ...}
```

**Store**

```
{ StoreID(INT), Location(varchar), ...}
```

**Inventory**

```
 {StoreID(INT) references Store(StoreID) ,ProdID(INT) references Products(ProdID),...}
```

I want the list of products not available in each store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT P.ProdID 
         , S.StoreID
    FROM Product P CROSS JOIN Store S
   )
SELECT C.StoreID, C.ProdID
FROM CTE C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Inventory
                  WHERE C.StoreID = StoreID 
                   AND  C.ProdID  = ProdID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you want to select all stores that do not have products in inventory.

```
select s.StoreID, p.ProdID, p.Name
  from Store s, (select ProdID, Name 
                   from Product
                  where ProdID not in (select i.ProdID 
                                         from inventory i
                                        where i.StoreID = s.StoreID
                                      )
                ) p
 order by s.StoreID, p.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    productID, count_storeID
FROM
    (SELECT
        productid,
        COUNT(DISTINCT storeid) AS count_storeID
    FROM
        inventory
    GROUP BY 
        productID) i FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_stores FROM storeID   ) s
WHERE
    count_storeID < count_stores
```